# How to load the data images (Nifti files) instead of a series of Jpeg images?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was using this code to load the data images and masks it was working perfect, now I want to use it for Nifti files instead of a series of Jpeg images ( just for images and the masks will remain as a series of Jpeg images).

```
def load_data(path, split=0.1):
  images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "1.nii.gz")))
  masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(path, "GT for sub DynaCT data set 3/*")))

  total_size = len(images)
  valid_size = int(split * total_size)
  test_size = int(split * total_size)

  train_x, valid_x = train_test_split(images, test_size=valid_size, random_state=42)
  train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(masks, test_size=valid_size, random_state=42)

  train_x, test_x = train_test_split(train_x, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
  train_y, test_y = train_test_split(train_y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)

  return (train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y), (test_x, test_y)

def read_image(path):
  path = path.decode()
  x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  x = cv2.resize(x, (256, 256))
  x = x/255.0
  return x

def read_mask(path):
  path = path.decode()
  x = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  x = cv2.resize(x, (256, 256))
  x = x/255.0
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
  return x

def tf_parse(x, y):
  def _parse(x, y):
      x = read_image(x)
      y = read_mask(y)
      return x, y

  x, y = tf.numpy_function(_parse, [x, y], [tf.float64, tf.float64])
  x.set_shape([256, 256, 3])
  y.set_shape([256, 256, 1])
  return x, y

def tf_dataset(x, y, batch=8):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
  dataset = dataset.map(tf_parse)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch)
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  return dataset
```

Here is the block error that appears to me during running the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/fadil/Desktop/Project/Segmentation/Under testing/Exp2_29112021/CT&DCT/DCT/U_Net_Segmentation_DynaCT/predict.py", line 53, in <module>
   test_dataset = tf_dataset(test_x, test_y, batch=batch_size)
 File "C:\Users\fadil\Desktop\Project\Segmentation\Under testing\Exp2_29112021\CT&DCT\DCT\U_Net_Segmentation_DynaCT\data.py", line 53, in tf_dataset
   dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
 File "C:\Users\fadil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 691, in from_tensor_slices
   return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
 File "C:\Users\fadil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 3165, in __init__
   tensor_shape.dimension_value(t.get_shape()[0])))
 File "C:\Users\fadil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 282, in assert_is_compatible_with
   (self, other))
ValueError: Dimensions 1 and 211 are not compatible

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please post the Error message in code block format, and not as an image. `Nifti` images are composed of the header and the images as explained [here](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html), deep learning is usually done on the images in `png` format to avoid lossy compression of `Jpeg`, or numpy arrays.

Comment: I attached the Error message in code block format in the image above with the question

Comment: please see this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and this [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I now replaced the image with the block of error.